# roots of combined e-function

Tags: real-analysis, roots

I need to determine the roots of the following function analytically:

$$f(x) = 1 - x - x \cdot e^{-2x}$$

This is my try on it:

$0 = 1 - x - x*e^{-2x}$

$-1 = - x - x*e^{-2x}$

$-1 + x = - x*e^{-2x}$

$\frac{1 - x}{x} = e^{-2x}$

$\ln(1 - x)-\ln(x) = -2x$

$-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1 - x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x) = x\quad $

It would be great if someone could give me a hand! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *Welcome to the site !*

This is a transcendental equation with no explicit solution.

Consider instead that you look for the zero'(s) of function
$$f(x) = 1 - x - x\,e^{-2x}$$ for which
$$f'(x)=e^{-2 x}\, (2 x-1)-1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=-4 e^{-2 x}\, (x-1)$$ By inspection $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=-\frac{1}{e^2}$. So, at least, we know that with have a root in the interval.

Now, consider using Newton method. Being lazy, start at the midpoint and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.50000000 \\
 1 & 0.81606028 \\
 2 & 0.84388748 \\
 3 & 0.84394700
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, try to prove that is no other root.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$f'(x) = -e^{-2x} \left(  e^{2x} -2x + 1\right)$$

This is always negative (why ?).

Moreover $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ (why ?).

You can deduce (why ?) that $f$ has exactly one root on $\mathbb{R}$.